# virtual host current content while leaving archive in tact

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

That's probably not the greatest subject line but I don't know how else to ask.

I am designing a website for an annual festival with each year's site in the root directory as a year (ie `/2012`, `/2011`, `/2010` etc.) We don't want the current year to show in the URL, so I've found out how to modify the .htaccess file like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/2012/
RewriteRule ^(.*) /2012/$1 [L]
```

Problem is, this way none of the archives are resolving properly and we want to keep a visible archive of past festivals. The end goal would be to have URLs like this

```
http://www.mysite.com/
http://www.mysite.com/2011/
http://www.mysite.com/2010/
http://www.mysite.com/2009/
```

How would I do this? Is it something that should be done through a rewrite should it be done with virtual host? I don't really understand this stuff and don't want to break the website!

Comment: This isn't really programming related. Try pointing `DirectoryIndex` to `2012/index.html`, then when someone requests `http://www.mysite.com/`, `2012/index.html` will be displayed. Eventually someone will move this to serverfault.com; where you are likely to get better responses.

Comment: Ah. I didn't realize there was a separate forum for server administration stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, your RewriteCond checks if the URI is not inside /2012/

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/2012/
```

Instead, you should check if it is not inside *any year* folder:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]{4}/
```

Comment: And what do you expect it to do? It's an old archived site... EDIT: Oops, apparently i am answering to a comment that has been removed ;)

Comment: Yeah, I made that comment then realized the file didn't actually overwrite the one on the live server :) thank you!! I figured it was something like that because of the "!" but couldn't work it out. It works perfectly now!